# How to make one object type which will contain properties of all objects of union type, but values will are intersections

Tags: typescript

How can I make a type which will make a one object type from unions of objects, which will contain properties of all objects of union type, but values will intersections?

Example: I need to make from type `{ foo: 1 } | { foo: 2; bar: 3 } | { foo: 7; bar: 8 }` a type `{foo: 1 | 2 | 7; bar: 3 | 8}`.

**Important note**: I want to make one object type instead of an intersection like `{foo: 1 | 2} & {bar: 3}`

I have written a type, `ComplexUnionToIntersection`, which should do it, but it's ignoring properties which do not exist in all objects of the union (`bar` in my examples).

My code:

```
/**
 * More info: https://fettblog.eu/typescript-union-to-intersection/
 */
export type UnionToIntersection<U> = (
    U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never
) extends (k: infer I) => void
    ? I
    : never;

/**
 * Target type
 */
export type ComplexUnionToIntersection<U> = { o: U } extends { o: infer X }
    ? {
            [K in keyof (X & U)]: (X & U)[K];
      }
    : UnionToIntersection<U>;
```

Test cases:

```
// TODO: result of test case must be `{foo: 1 | 2; bar: 3}`
type testCase1 = ComplexUnionToIntersection<{ foo: 1 } | { foo: 2; bar: 3 }>; // actually return `{ foo: 1 | 2; }`

// TODO: result of test case must be `{foo: 1 | 2 | 7; bar: 3 | 8}`
type testCase2 = ComplexUnionToIntersection<
    { foo: 1 } | { foo: 2; bar: 3 } | { foo: 7; bar: 8 }
>;

// TODO: result of test case must be `{foo: 1 | 2; bar: 3 | 8}`
type testCase3 = ComplexUnionToIntersection<
    { foo: 1 } | { foo: 2; bar: 3 } | { bar: 8 }
>;

// TODO: result of test case must be `{foo?: 1 | 2; bar: 3 | 8}`
type testCase4 = ComplexUnionToIntersection<
    { foo: 1 } | { foo?: 2; bar: 3 } | { bar: 8 }
>;
```

[TS Playground is here](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?ssl=35&ssc=3&pln=30&pc=3#code/PQKhCgAIUhZB7ATgU0gSwHYDN4C5IAWALkQA4DOuwwWyJARgDbwDmAdMgK7BECepycgGNEaUkQC0nDGngYJReBMxFkicsiFFZGYFBB7kAD1JIikPgMgBVGXIAq8AJIZV6zdrkAeawD5IALyQABTgAJDWkMaqGAAm5JAAhhi8kAD8IQDW+NYAlIH+AG7waLGQ+BjIhWrg+dHIcQnB2ejYapBO+QFFJbHhGU7hFVVqANzg4KAQ0JD2iYgsdBb8yPqGJmbLVgDC8AC2pIzGtjqOLm4aWjo+-kEA3pB4NpAAvlFGMfGQD0+YtIiQAAar3633CYTCAG0ANKtSCZZC8eBYELAgBkNlyAF18MF0ZiYVjxmFICCwjk7Bgzq41JdPBgbuNJsBZgB5AAirPwKHInEY5mRFkE5iEiQ0kD2nHI5noqAABnccE8AIyQAA+kAATKNIPR5vgAMwvOXgSyoVTS7Zi5CqoK7A5HIwnBzOGnuK7eB5K-Cqt4ar3wJ7a3X6yAG16+JnUNmc7mCPkClEWkXWiVSmXyxWBn3qrW5gDsOr1iENuYAHMbTSshZbrZrApB7YdjpTqRcPNdwgGVa9c938MHi6W-d9IN7IIWQyXIGWQZGJtH7ByuZAeQnHknhZBReLJdLdZnx6qNYPQ+GNRWTWaa0QrRpw3b9s2na3Xe2PQyu2Ps5BfX3v0GRZnr2-pTvgs4vOA87MjGK5rvyG43tuqZ7hmkAKkqaQ5ieQHTueM6VteyZ3sgAAsDZNo6zpUm+tIdt4X5HiBo6YQOuHDv+Q4znOoxAA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wQVAAN) work for your use cases?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  Note that you write your `TestCase3` requirement doesn't match up with what the code produces; I assume that's a typo on your part, but if it isn't I'd need to hear more of an explanation for what you're trying to do. Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz you're right, i mistype. Thank you, it's exact that i need. Please, make answer and i mark it as solution. Only one problem is still exist - optional parameters is not work. Is you know how we can fix it? Example type: `{ foo: 1 } | { foo?: 2; bar: 3 } | { foo: 7; bar: 8 }`

Comment: Please explain what type should come out: “is not work” is unfortunately not descriptive enough for me to understand. Ideally you will [edit] your question so the code is a [mre] that details the necessary use cases.

Comment: Okay, please test [this version](https://tsplay.dev/wEvVvN) against your use cases.  If there is anything else missing let me know (and hopefully [edit] the question to demo the need if it's not already in there).

Comment: @jcalz wow, you are wizard. Thank you, it's solve my problem. Could you write answer with explaining how it work? It will be useful for all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the operation is to merge a union of object types into a single object type, where each property key in *any* of the input union members will appear in the output type, and the value type of that property will be the union of all property value types for that key wherever it appears in the input.  *And* you want a property to be optional in the ouput if it's optional in *any* of the input union members.

If you just collapse the union into a single object type, you'll have the problem you see where a property will only exist in the output if it exists in *every* input, but otherwise the property types will be correct.  So one approach here would be to first augment each member of the union so it contains all the keys from any union member.  So if a property is missing, we should add it, and give it the value type of [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), which is absorbed in any union.

For example, we start with something like:

```
{ foo: 1 } | { foo?: 2; bar: 3 } | { bar: 8 }
```

And then augment each member of the union to contain all the keys, something like:

```
{ foo: 1; bar: never } | { foo?: 2; bar: 3 } | { foo: never; bar: 8 }
```

And then we merge this new union into a single object, like:

```
{ foo?: 1 | 2 | never; bar: never | 3 | 8 }
```

which collapses to

```
{ foo?: 1 | 2; bar: 3 | 8 }
```

So let's do it:

---

```
type AllKeys<T> = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never

type AddMissingProps<T, K extends PropertyKey = AllKeys<T>> =
    T extends unknown ? (T & Record<Exclude<K, keyof T>, never>) : never;

type MyMerge<T> = { [K in keyof AddMissingProps<T>]: AddMissingProps<T>[K] }
```

The `AllKeys<T>` type is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) which gathers every key from every union member:

```
type TestAllKeys = AllKeys<{ foo: 1 } | { foo?: 2; bar: 3 } | { bar: 8 }>
// type TestAllKeys = "foo" | "bar"
```

The `AddMissingProps<T, K>` type is also distributive, and for each element of the input union `T` it adds any keys from `K` which are not already present in `keyof T`, and gives them a `never` type, and note that `K` defaults to `AllKeys<T>`:

```
type TestAddMissingProps = AddMissingProps<{ foo: 1 } | { foo?: 2; bar: 3 } | { bar: 8 }>
/* type TestAddMissingProps = 
    ({ foo: 1; } & Record<"bar", never>) | 
    ({ foo?: 2 | undefined; bar: 3; } & Record<never, never>) | 
    ({ bar: 8; } & Record<"foo", never>) */
```

That is equivalent to the `{ foo: 1; bar: never } | { foo?: 2; bar: 3 } | { foo: never; bar: 8 }` type mentioned above, although it's not written the same way.  Since we are still going to process the type it's not important to reduce it here.

Finally, the `MyMerge<T>` type is an *identity* [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over `AddMissingProps<T>`.  Its only purpose is to iterate over each property and produce a single object type output:

```
type TestMyMerge = MyMerge<{ foo: 1 } | { foo?: 2; bar: 3 } | { bar: 8 }>
/* type TestMyMerge = {
    foo?: 1 | 2 | undefined;
    bar: 3 | 8;
} */
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA0hEBnAPAFQHxQLxSZQQAewEAdgCapQCuFA1hQPYDuFUA-FIyiwDNCUAFxQKEAG4QATgCg5oSLCpUAsgEtUqDRQDmABRkswGTABooiYmUo0oRk7NDIQ+WAldnsuPHKgBwqTk1LQMzOycPAAURABkUABKEADGLDJU6ACiJClwdFQQ6IiWfCCChNiWEtIy2ACUouJSsgDcCkrQaiBqsnpFOO4A3lAA2ta6vPxCMKqa2rqGxqZY2AC6YrPqWjr6jis442tQAL4d4NCYEKjA8EgotAR3XugjAiwsYgCMp1AAPlA3h8uGIAEytKAAIwAhjIxABmX4AkYwuFQAAcp2wcgA9DioJ1CNdbp4Hu4AETvFjk-5Qcmo8nnZRXG5bea7JYmR4qbYLPbLDBAz5QH4nWlCkFQcFQ2EIpGAmVozEnbE4gBUBIuRNZcx2i323OiQ38gSp33aYoSyTSGXQ9Nh5OqLTqjQBRpNASpktBtIYhQEuggVHagUVCItUCtqXSmRqsidtQatPdodRYnREajNsylI+juaicaapxTMuxO6vRk-XcFb6RSF33lErBELTUERYuRYYxWNxGsJLOAtar0AIxtDXsbAJ9AL9EADEmDHu7iIBGbkYuLCjxhAA8gARXdiGTXOhwYBQCrkG5QFLQ1DQAC2dBvkOgAAMhmaRbTpW34Sc76KFqg4AML3hAPwEMO-SvFA36iuK8EfC2K5Yu0uL4pgB5HlAJ6oGeF5XsSt4QVAz6vh+X4oT+060gA7K2srtrS6KAcBzLEuBD4+tBPR1ugy4Nj+nYKt+f7MR2SHfox3bKnI2AYTu2GHsep7npeQjXhed4PuRL4Xm+UCfghv5MWiq4YoBUAcWWNzcRAiJ8ZWsFCchwqIV24nmXKokosx8mKduWE4WpBEacRN66U+BlQlRk60VKPksWu7EDlxEEACw1vxI6CaGwmeWJwKof+TZyacCntEAA)